# Best way to send and receive data(POST and GET) from Android to web server using Java?

Tags: java, android, http, asynchronous, system.reactive

In my Android Studio project I am using Java and I have Room database combined with LiveData and ViewModel.

I want to upload some of the tables from Room database(make post requests to a PHP script) and also be able to download( GET request from web server ).

My question is what is the best approach for this?
Is a good idea to use Android Studio AsyncTask or should I use RxJava for network calls in order to prevent blocking UI?
I think about using okHttp for send and receiving data.

Comment: The retrofit library is very common among Android devs for REST API calls:
https://square.github.io/retrofit/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Android there's some alternatives for send HTTP Rest Request from your App but the most simple and easy to configure is [Retrofit](https://square.github.io/retrofit/), this library allows to call to your Rest API from your Android App and you can Attach multiple configurations for Logging, Messaging, etc. Another library that you can use is [RxJava](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava)